# SLF4J NoSuchMethodError on LocationAwareLogger

Tags: java, maven, jar, dependencies, slf4j

This is a question that has been asked before, but unfortunately no solution seems to work for me. I am facing this exception (with abridged stack trace):

```
java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: org.slf4j.spi.LocationAwareLogger.log(Lorg/slf4j/Marker;Ljava/lang/String;ILjava/lang/String;[Ljava/lang/Object;Ljava/lang/Throwable;)V
    at org.apache.commons.logging.impl.SLF4JLocationAwareLog.debug(SLF4JLocationAwareLog.java:133)
    at org.apache.http.impl.conn.tsccm.ThreadSafeClientConnManager$1.getConnection(ThreadSafeClientConnManager.java:221)
    at org.apache.http.impl.client.DefaultRequestDirector.execute(DefaultRequestDirector.java:401)
    at org.apache.http.impl.client.AbstractHttpClient.execute(AbstractHttpClient.java:820)
```

This happens when compiling using a command line Maven and also when deploying to Tomcat. It works fine inside IntelliJ IDEA.

Usually I would expect this to be caused by multiple versions of the SLF4J library being in use. But the Maven dependency tree shows all slf4j libraries in a single version:

```
..$ mvn dependency:tree | grep slf4j
[INFO] +- org.slf4j:slf4j-simple:jar:1.6.4:compile
[INFO] |  \- org.slf4j:slf4j-api:jar:1.6.4:compile
[INFO] +- org.slf4j:slf4j-api:jar:1.6.4:compile
[INFO] +- org.slf4j:jcl-over-slf4j:jar:1.6.4:compile
[INFO] +- org.slf4j:slf4j-simple:jar:1.6.4:compile
```

I even ensured that there is no other JAR in ~/.m2/repository

There are no references to commons-logging libraries either (I excluded them all as confirmed by the dependency tree.

How can I resolve this issue? I'm running out of ideas.

EDIT: as requested here the full dependencies, first the parent POM:

```
<dependencyManagement>
    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.hibernate</groupId>
            <artifactId>hibernate-validator</artifactId>
            <version>${org.hibernate.validator.version}</version>
            <exclusions>
                <!-- Exclude SLF4j to avoid version conflicts (we have 1.6.2, this drags in 1.6.1) -->
                <exclusion>
                    <groupId>org.slf4j</groupId>
                    <artifactId>slf4j-api</artifactId>
                </exclusion>
            </exclusions>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.hibernate</groupId>
            <artifactId>hibernate-validator-annotation-processor</artifactId>
            <version>${org.hibernate.validator.version}</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>javax.validation</groupId>
            <artifactId>validation-api</artifactId>
            <version>1.0.0.GA</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-context</artifactId>
            <version>${org.springframework.version}</version>
            <exclusions>
                <!-- Exclude Commons Logging in favor of SLF4j -->
                <exclusion>
                    <groupId>commons-logging</groupId>
                    <artifactId>commons-logging</artifactId>
                </exclusion>
            </exclusions>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-webmvc</artifactId>
            <version>${org.springframework.version}</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.security</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-security-config</artifactId>
            <version>${org.springframework.version}</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.security</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-security-core</artifactId>
            <version>${org.springframework.version}</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.security</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-security-web</artifactId>
            <version>${org.springframework.version}</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.security</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-security-taglibs</artifactId>
            <version>${org.springframework.version}</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>javax.inject</groupId>
            <artifactId>javax.inject</artifactId>
            <version>1</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>junit</groupId>
            <artifactId>junit</artifactId>
            <version>4.8.2</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.slf4j</groupId>
            <artifactId>${org.slf4j.backend}</artifactId>
            <version>${org.slf4j.version}</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.hsqldb</groupId>
            <artifactId>hsqldb</artifactId>
            <version>2.2.4</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.httpcomponents</groupId>
            <artifactId>httpclient</artifactId>
            <version>4.1.2</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>joda-time</groupId>
            <artifactId>joda-time</artifactId>
            <version>2.0</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>joda-time</groupId>
            <artifactId>joda-time-jsptags</artifactId>
            <version>1.0.2</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>javax.servlet</groupId>
            <artifactId>servlet-api</artifactId>
            <version>2.5</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>javax.servlet.jsp</groupId>
            <artifactId>jsp-api</artifactId>
            <version>2.1</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>javax.servlet</groupId>
            <artifactId>jstl</artifactId>
            <version>1.2</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>postgresql</groupId>
            <artifactId>postgresql</artifactId>
            <version>9.0-801.jdbc4</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.commons</groupId>
            <artifactId>commons-lang3</artifactId>
            <version>3.0.1</version>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>
</dependencyManagement>
```

And then the module that fails:

```
<dependencies>
    // client specific dependencies skipped //

    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.google.guava</groupId>
        <artifactId>guava</artifactId>
        <version>10.0.1</version>
    </dependency>

    <!-- Spring -->
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-context</artifactId>
        <exclusions>
            <!-- Exclude Commons Logging in favor of SLF4j -->
            <exclusion>
                <groupId>commons-logging</groupId>
                <artifactId>commons-logging</artifactId>
            </exclusion>
        </exclusions>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-webmvc</artifactId>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.security</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-security-config</artifactId>
        <scope>runtime</scope>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.security</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-security-core</artifactId>
        <scope>compile</scope>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.security</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-security-web</artifactId>
        <scope>compile</scope>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.security</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-security-taglibs</artifactId>
        <scope>runtime</scope>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>javax.inject</groupId>
        <artifactId>javax.inject</artifactId>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>cglib</groupId>
        <artifactId>cglib</artifactId>
        <version>2.2.2</version>
    </dependency>

    <!-- Logging -->
    <dependency>
        <groupId>net.sf.opencsv</groupId>
        <artifactId>opencsv</artifactId>
        <version>2.0</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.slf4j</groupId>
        <artifactId>slf4j-api</artifactId>
        <version>${org.slf4j.version}</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.slf4j</groupId>
        <artifactId>jcl-over-slf4j</artifactId>
        <version>${org.slf4j.version}</version>
        <scope>runtime</scope>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.slf4j</groupId>
        <artifactId>${org.slf4j.backend}</artifactId>
        <version>${org.slf4j.version}</version>
        <scope>runtime</scope>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>log4j</groupId>
        <artifactId>log4j</artifactId>
        <version>1.2.16</version>
    </dependency>

    <!-- Joda Time -->
    <dependency>
        <groupId>joda-time</groupId>
        <artifactId>joda-time</artifactId>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>joda-time</groupId>
        <artifactId>joda-time-jsptags</artifactId>
        <scope>runtime</scope>
    </dependency>

    <!-- Servlet -->
    <dependency>
        <groupId>javax.servlet</groupId>
        <artifactId>servlet-api</artifactId>
        <scope>provided</scope>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>javax.servlet.jsp</groupId>
        <artifactId>jsp-api</artifactId>
        <scope>provided</scope>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>javax.servlet</groupId>
        <artifactId>jstl</artifactId>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.google.visualization</groupId>
        <artifactId>visualization-datasource</artifactId>
        <version>1.0.2</version>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.mybatis</groupId>
        <artifactId>mybatis-spring</artifactId>
        <version>1.0.2</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>commons-dbcp</groupId>
        <artifactId>commons-dbcp</artifactId>
        <version>1.4</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.codehaus.jackson</groupId>
        <artifactId>jackson-mapper-asl</artifactId>
        <version>1.9.0</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>commons-io</groupId>
        <artifactId>commons-io</artifactId>
        <version>2.1</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>commons-fileupload</groupId>
        <artifactId>commons-fileupload</artifactId>
        <version>1.2.2</version>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.apache.poi</groupId>
        <artifactId>poi</artifactId>
        <version>3.7</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.apache.poi</groupId>
        <artifactId>poi-ooxml</artifactId>
        <version>3.7</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.apache.poi</groupId>
        <artifactId>poi-ooxml-schemas</artifactId>
        <version>3.7</version>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>postgresql</groupId>
        <artifactId>postgresql</artifactId>
        <scope>runtime</scope>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <scope>test</scope>
        <groupId>junit</groupId>
        <artifactId>junit</artifactId>
    </dependency>
</dependencies>
```

These are the properties set on the parent:

```
<properties>
    <project.build.sourceEncoding>UTF-8</project.build.sourceEncoding>
    <org.hibernate.validator.version>4.2.0.Final</org.hibernate.validator.version>
    <org.slf4j.backend>slf4j-simple</org.slf4j.backend>
    <org.slf4j.version>1.6.4</org.slf4j.version>
    <org.springframework.version>3.0.5.RELEASE</org.springframework.version>
</properties>
```

Given my recent experiments it doesn't seem to be an issue relating to the project files, though. I tried to 'hg bisect' the problem, but going back weeks I could not find a version that works. Some of these are running in production systems, so it is not likely to be a code change that causes this problem.

Comment: Can you share the dependencies from you pom.xml?

Answer (score 24, accepted):

The javadocs for NoSuchMethodError say,

> Normally, this error is caught by the compiler; this error can 
>    only occur at run time if the definition of a class has incompatibly changed.

So this is probably being caused by incompatible versions of slf4j being loaded. Rather than looking at your classpath and guessing where classes are loaded, find where your class is loaded as described [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/227486/find-where-java-class-is-loaded-from).

Print out where `org.slf4j.spi.LocationAwareLogger`, `org.apache.commons.logging.impl.SLF4JLocationAwareLog` and `org.slf4j.Marker` are being loaded from.

Comment: I should have thought about asking the class loader. It turns out https://www.auskey.abr.gov.au was the culprit: they dumped a copy of a 1.5.8 slf4j into /usr/java/packages/lib/ext/ when I installed their key 5 days ago. There's more scary stuff in there (log4j, bcmail, jaxb...) -- I'll need to set up a separate JRE. I wish slf4j would stop breaking binary compatibility, though.

Comment: Just hit exactly this problem after installing auskey!  Thanks for the comment, @PeterBecker.

Comment: I'm able to import the classes mentioned in this answer (as in the IDE doesn't complain about not finding them), but when I try to run the code which is supposed to display where they are loaded from, I get a compilation error: ``package does not exist`` and ``cannot find symbol``. Yet ``slf4j`` is in my classpath, and only one version too.

Comment: @payne I would have used a clean JRE (it's been a while), but it was a problem different to yours. You may be having the dependency on the IDE's library set, but not the runtime classpath. It might need it's own question.

Answer (score 4):

I had the same error message, but the solution was different for me. I had to **remove** to following dependency from the maven pom:

```
<dependency>
  <groupId>org.slf4j</groupId>
  <artifactId>jcl-over-slf4j</artifactId>
  <version>1.6.1</version>
</dependency>
```

After that the error vanishes and everything worked for me.

Comment: I added it as `provided` dependency in my parent pom

Comment: If it was there in the first place, there might have been a reason why?

Answer (score 1):

One Solution.

Verify on eclipse directory: configuration\org.eclipse.equinox.simpleconfigurator\bundles.info

slf4j no more one

Answer (score 1):

do

mvn clean dependency:tree -DskipTests;

remove all the dependencies of "org.slf4j" except one (highest one") as

```
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
        <artifactId>maven-jar-plugin</artifactId>
        <version>2.6</version>
        <exclusions>
            <exclusion>
                <groupId>org.slf4j</groupId>
                <artifactId>slf4j-jdk14</artifactId>
            </exclusion>
            <exclusion>
                <groupId>org.slf4j</groupId>
                <artifactId>jcl-over-slf4j</artifactId>
            </exclusion>
        </exclusions>
    </dependency>
```

Answer (score 1):

We were facing the similar problem and it turned out we had 2 incompatible versions of slf4j jars in the classpath. 
The class path had the following 2 incompatible versions. After removing the lower versions from the classpath, the problem was fixed.

slf4j-api-1.6.1.jar 
slf4j-log4j12-1.6.1.jar

slf4j-api-1.5.11.jar 
slf4j-log4j12-1.5.11.jar

Answer (score 1):

Solved !!!

I was having dependency on another project which was using `JavaDoc` plugin.
`JavaDoc` plugin internally uses `Maven-core` and `Maven-core-2.2.1` uses `jcl-over-slf4j: 1.5.6`.
`Maven-core` is a parent level jar.

Now, due to this `JCL` jar, i was facing this issue.
Hence I removed it from the `lib` folder of `weblogic`(or whatever server you might be using).

And ALAS !! The problem was resolved.

Note 1:- You can also use Maven's `<exclusion>` tag to remove this dependency from the `JavaDoc`(or any other plugin) to resolve this issue.

Note 2:- Use the `Dependency Hierarchy` tab in POM to see if any such old `SLF4J` jars are present. And remove rest and keep only one version.

Hope it helps ..

Answer (score 1):

This usually happens when you have dependencies that both use the same transitive dependency. This means that 2 of your dependencies (or your app, and a transitive dependency) are both using SLF4J internally with different versions. But your app can only use a single version of the class at the same time so it has to choose (don't know the rules here... random?)

To solve the problem, you usually need to do a `mvn dependency:tree` to see which are using different versions of SLF4J.

Adding this dependency solved the issue for me

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.slf4j</groupId>
    <artifactId>slf4j-api</artifactId>
    <version>1.7.25</version>
</dependency>

<dependency>
    <groupId>org.slf4j</groupId>
    <artifactId>slf4j-log4j12</artifactId>
    <version>1.7.5</version>
</dependency>
```

Answer (score 0):

I had quartz scheduler in my pom file, which included slf4j, so I excluded it:

```
<exclusion>
    <groupId>org.slf4j</groupId>
    <artifactId>slf4j-api</artifactId>
</exclusion>
```

and worked!