# Eclipse, junit, Hibernate An internal error occurred during: "Fetching children of Database"

Tags: eclipse, hibernate, hibernate-tools

When i'm trying to open hibernate perspective in Eclipse, i receive the above error, with the following stacktrace:

```
java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: org.slf4j.spi.LocationAwareLogger.log(Lorg/slf4j/Marker;Ljava/lang/String;ILjava/lang/String;[Ljava/lang/Object;Ljava/lang/Throwable;)V
at org.apache.commons.logging.impl.SLF4JLocationAwareLog.debug(SLF4JLocationAwareLog.java:133)
at org.hibernate.cfg.reveng.dialect.JDBCMetaDataDialect.getTables(JDBCMetaDataDialect.java:26)
at org.hibernate.cfg.reveng.JDBCReader.processTables(JDBCReader.java:476)
at org.hibernate.cfg.reveng.JDBCReader.readDatabaseSchema(JDBCReader.java:74)
at org.hibernate.eclipse.console.workbench.LazyDatabaseSchemaWorkbenchAdapter$2.execute(LazyDatabaseSchemaWorkbenchAdapter.java:126)
at org.hibernate.console.execution.DefaultExecutionContext.execute(DefaultExecutionContext.java:63)
at org.hibernate.console.ConsoleConfiguration.execute(ConsoleConfiguration.java:107)
at org.hibernate.eclipse.console.workbench.LazyDatabaseSchemaWorkbenchAdapter.readDatabaseSchema(LazyDatabaseSchemaWorkbenchAdapter.java:115)
at org.hibernate.eclipse.console.workbench.LazyDatabaseSchemaWorkbenchAdapter.getChildren(LazyDatabaseSchemaWorkbenchAdapter.java:65)
at org.hibernate.eclipse.console.workbench.BasicWorkbenchAdapter.fetchDeferredChildren(BasicWorkbenchAdapter.java:106)
at org.eclipse.ui.progress.DeferredTreeContentManager$1.run(DeferredTreeContentManager.java:235)
at org.eclipse.core.internal.jobs.Worker.run(Worker.java:53)
```

This is my pom.xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd"
    xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>

    <repositories>
        <repository>
            <id>caf</id>
            <name>caf-repo</name>
            <url>http://artifactory.fao.org/artifactory/caf-release-local</url>
        </repository>
    </repositories>
    <groupId>org.fao.fipdt</groupId>
    <artifactId>fip-dt</artifactId>
    <version>1.0-SNAPSHOT</version>
    <packaging>war</packaging>

    <name>FIP-Dt Tool</name>
    <properties>
        <org.springframework.version>3.2.0.RELEASE</org.springframework.version>
        <javax.servlet.jstl.version>1.2</javax.servlet.jstl.version>
    </properties>

    <profiles>
        <profile>
            <id>development</id>
            <activation>
                <activeByDefault>true</activeByDefault>
            </activation>
            <properties>
                ...
            </properties>
        </profile>
    </profiles>

    <dependencies>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-context</artifactId>
            <version>3.2.0.RELEASE</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-core</artifactId>
            <version>3.2.0.RELEASE</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.data</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-data-jpa</artifactId>
            <version>1.0.1.RELEASE</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-test</artifactId>
            <version>3.2.0.RELEASE</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-webmvc</artifactId>
            <version>3.2.0.RELEASE</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-orm</artifactId>
            <version>3.2.0.RELEASE</version>
        </dependency>


        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-tx</artifactId>
            <version>3.2.0.RELEASE</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-beans</artifactId>
            <version>3.2.0.RELEASE</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.fao.caf</groupId>
            <artifactId>caf-client</artifactId>
            <version>3.3.3</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>javax.servlet</groupId>
            <artifactId>servlet-api</artifactId>
            <version>2.5</version>
        </dependency>


        <dependency>
            <groupId>commons-dbcp</groupId>
            <artifactId>commons-dbcp</artifactId>
            <version>1.4</version>
        </dependency>


        <dependency>
            <groupId>javax.servlet</groupId>
            <artifactId>jstl</artifactId>
            <version>${javax.servlet.jstl.version}</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>log4j</groupId>
            <artifactId>log4j</artifactId>
            <version>1.2.16</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>junit</groupId>
            <artifactId>junit</artifactId>
            <version>4.8.1</version>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>commons-logging</groupId>
            <artifactId>commons-logging</artifactId>
            <version>1.1.1</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>mysql</groupId>
            <artifactId>mysql-connector-java</artifactId>
            <version>5.1.21</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>commons-collections</groupId>
            <artifactId>commons-collections</artifactId>
            <version>20040616</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.hibernate</groupId>
            <artifactId>hibernate-core</artifactId>
            <version>4.1.9.Final</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.hibernate</groupId>
            <artifactId>hibernate-entitymanager</artifactId>
            <version>4.1.9.Final</version>
        </dependency>


    </dependencies>

    <build>

        <finalName>fip-dt</finalName>

        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
                <configuration>
                    <source>1.6</source>
                    <target>1.6</target>
                    <encoding>UTF8</encoding>
                </configuration>
                <inherited>true</inherited>
            </plugin>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-eclipse-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>2.9</version>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>

        <resources>
            <resource>
                <directory>src/main/resources</directory>
                <filtering>true</filtering>
                <includes>
                    <include>**/*.xml</include>
                </includes>
            </resource>
        </resources>
        <testResources>
            <testResource>
                <directory>src/test/resources</directory>
                <filtering>true</filtering>
                <includes>
                    <include>**/*.xml</include>
                </includes>
            </testResource>
            <testResource>
                <directory>src/main/resources</directory>
                <filtering>true</filtering>
                <includes>
                    <include>**/*.xml</include>
                </includes>
            </testResource>
        </testResources>
    </build>
</project>
```

I looked through the site, and i'm aware that the problem is about sfl4j inclusion, but unfortunately i tried to exclude it, update it, add a dependency, but every try fails.

The version that i can see from dependency hierarchi is 1.6.1, and is the same version that was in the hibernate core pom (but in that one the scope is test.

The library contains that class and method, but i don't know why hibernate tools cannot find them.

I tried with Spring Tool Suite ide, and with a fresh eclipse juno installation.

I'm running out of ideas.  :(

Comment: Your problem is probably similar to [this one](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8252597/slf4j-nosuchmethoderror-on-locationawarelogger).

Comment: i tried, but it didn't solved the problem.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Review your project pom and eclipse configuration: you've two different versions of log4j/slf4j.

Answer (score 0):

The problem is with two or more versions of the same jar in the classpath as indicated by David.

In this situation you may try these:

•Your hibernate tools plugin (< eclipse_directory >/plugins/) and your project maven repository (< user_directory >/.m2/repository/org/slf4j) have different SLF4J jar version. Maintain same version in both of these folders (read classpath). Keep the latest one in both of these and delete the older one. It's a dirty hack but an acceptable way to keep jar versions in-sync.

•Another (better) way, keep your data access objects in a separate project. Create a simple maven POJO project and automate code generation through hibernate tools. Import this project into the project where you're maintaining business logic. This is a standard design in big projects and, the good part, you don't have to suffer the version conflict.