# NoSuchMethodError slf4j in a Play framework project

Tags: java, scala, playframework

I'm getting the following error on my Mac when running a play project:

```
[error] java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: org.slf4j.spi.LocationAwareLogger.log(Lorg/slf4j/Marker;Ljava/lang/String;ILjava/lang/String;[Ljava/lang/Object;Ljava/lang/Throwable;)V
```

I'm running Play 2.0.4 with 1.6.4 for slf4j.

Comment: As a rule, `NoSuchMethodError` indicates a version mismatch, in this case for SLF4J. See for instance this question with the same scenario - it turned out that SLF4J 1.5.x was also loaded.
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8252597/slf4j-nosuchmethoderror-on-locationawarelogger

Comment: +1 to the previous comment. You can try adding ``addSbtPlugin("net.virtual-void" % "sbt-dependency-graph" % "0.7.3")`` to your ``plugins.sbt`` and then running ``sbt dependency-graph`` or ``sbt test:dependency-tree`` to find out what dependency pulls in the bad version of SLF4J.