# Why do I keep getting NoSuchMethodError on LocationAwareLogger when running Jetty?

Tags: java, maven, jetty, slf4j

I'm trying to embed Jetty server into my automated tests so I've added the following dependency in my project:

```
<dependency>
  <groupId>org.eclipse.jetty</groupId>
  <artifactId>jetty-servlet</artifactId>
  <version>7.6.13.v20130916</version>
  <scope>test</scope>
</dependency>
```

I'm using Jetty 7 because the Web app uses Java 6, Servlet 2.5.

However when I try to start embedded Jetty server, I get:

```
java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: org.slf4j.spi.LocationAwareLogger.log(Lorg/slf4j/Marker;Ljava/lang/String;ILjava/lang/String;[Ljava/lang/Object;Ljava/lang/Throwable;)V
    at org.eclipse.jetty.util.log.JettyAwareLogger.log(JettyAwareLogger.java:607)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.util.log.JettyAwareLogger.warn(JettyAwareLogger.java:431)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.util.log.Slf4jLog.warn(Slf4jLog.java:69)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.util.component.AbstractLifeCycle.setFailed(AbstractLifeCycle.java:204)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.util.component.AbstractLifeCycle.start(AbstractLifeCycle.java:74)
```

I've been trying to figure out what's wrong but none of the steps I've taken so far addresses the issue. Here's a list of what I've done so far:

- Trace transitive dependencies to search for incompatible versions of `slf4j-api`
- Try out different versions of `slf4j-api` (1.5.11, 1.6.1, 1.6.4, 1.7.5)
- Looked into the some sources of Jetty 7 particularly the pom.xml and found that there's a dependency to slf4j 1.6.1
- Looked into [this similar question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8252597/slf4j-nosuchmethoderror-on-locationawarelogger) and got `null` when trying to print `org.slf4j.spi.LocationAwareLogger`, and `org.slf4j.Marker`

I hope someone can offer a fresh insight into this issue. Thanks.

Comment: Have you tried to specify <exclusion> for slf4j on jetty-servlet dependency?

Comment: jetty-servlet does not seem to have the transitive dependency to slf4j, which seems weird.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I bet you've faced a [compatibility problem](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3519978/logging-framework-incompatibility) between `sl4j` jars. Try examinating `mvn dependency:tree` output of your final artifact. Maybe you have two different versions of some `sl4j` jar and you cannot predict which loads first. Try to equalize all `sl4j` versions.

---

OP: Please refer to the [documentation on how I resolved this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/19133662/404604).

Comment: I've even made it to the point where there's absolutely no slf4j in the dependency tree, to ensure that when I add it specifically, all transitive dependencies have been excluded completely.

Comment: If there are no `sl4j` jars at all, then you'd got `NoClassDefFoundError` as `JettyAwareLogger` contains references to `sl4j` SPI classes. So, the classes are present at runtime. Where are they came from? Maybe it's you container `lib` folder? Or maybe you depend on a repackaged jar, which already contains `sl4j` classes?

Comment: Do you know of any way I could verify this? What I've done so far is, since I'm using Eclipse, import `LocationAwareLogger` in any class, then try to trace it to check if it's getting imported from the `slf4j` jar in the build path. I can't import it if I don't have any dependency to `slf4j`, but as you've noticed, I'm not getting a `NoClassDefFoundError`, which I've also been trying to deliberately raise.

Comment: **1** Start JVM with `-verbose:class` option _or_
**2** While in Eclipse debug stop on any breakpoint and show `Display` view. Type `org.slf4j.spi.LocationAwareLogger.class.getResource(org.slf4j.spi.LocationAwareLogger.class.getSimpleName() + ".class")` in it, select  and press `Display Result of Evaluating Selected Text`. You'll see where the class come from.

Comment: If using jetty standalone, use `$ java -jar start.jar --version` and see the server classpath.  Then look at your webapp's `WEB-INF/lib` tree.  Finally, set the [`jetty.dump.start`](https://github.com/eclipse/jetty.project/blob/master/jetty-distribution/src/main/resources/start.ini#L77) in your standalone jetty to `true` to see a dump of the webapp classpath.

Comment: I've got this issue addressed. Thanks. Refer to the documentation of the steps I took to resolve it: http://stackoverflow.com/a/19133662/404604.

Comment: can you help on this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/44091042/nosuchmethoderror-org-slf4j

Answer (score 3):

The information on [madhead](https://stackoverflow.com/users/750510/madhead)'s [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/19072360/404604) was very helpful but I'm going to document the details of what I've done for the sake for others who (will) encounter the same problem.

As the answer mentioned suggested, it was a problem with `slf4j` jars. To verify I did the following:

1. Define exclusion on all dependencies that have dependencies on `slf4j`.
2. Follow option 2 from [this suggestion](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19071485/why-do-i-keep-getting-nosuchmethoderror-on-locationawarelogger-when-running-jett#comment28192653_19072360).

   - I wrote a unit test that just sysout's a String of my choosing, and define a breakpoint at that line.
   - Then I debug the test as JUnit test, and open the Display view
   - I needed to re-run it because `Display Result of Evaluating Selected Text` was disabled at first for some reason.
   - I found out that the runtime still refers to the 1.5.8 version of `slf4j` that was still being added into the classpath regardless if I specified exclusion for it.
3. The project I'm working on depends on another project I'm also working on (it's a multi-Maven project project), which specified dependency to `slf4j-jdk14 1.5.8`, so I just updated it to `1.6.1`.

   - I had to specify exclusion of `slf4j-api` under `slf4j-jdk14 1.6.1` because it was referring to version 1.5.8, and add direct dependency to `slf4j-api 1.6.1`.