# Java - how to get the top level folder in which your java code is located?

Tags: java

This is the folder structure. Folder1 ---> Folder2, Folder3. Inside 3 there is java code.
How do I make java code which will be able to search the top level folder (ie 1) for a file or folder?  Is this even possible ?

Comment: its possible, but what have u tried?

Comment: It can search relative to where the class is loaded from, not where the (source) code is. Elaborate on your question, with example.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

This code gets the path -

```
String absolutePath = new File(".").getAbsolutePath();
System.out.println(absolutePath);// Shows you the path of your Project Folder
int last = absolutePath.length()-1;
absolutePath = absolutePath.substring(0, last);//Remove the dot at the end of path
System.out.println(absolutePath);
String filePath =  "MyFolderInsideEclipseProject\\file.txt";//You know this
System.out.println(absolutePath + filePath);//Get the full path.
```

Comment: `new File(".")` is the *current directory*, not where the class is loaded from. There are other similar questions on SO, for example [Find where java class is loaded from](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/227486/find-where-java-class-is-loaded-from/227640#227640), if it is location of the class files you are interested in.

Answer (score 3):

I think you can use [File's getParent() method](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/io/File.html#getParent%28%29) to do your desire job.

Comment: And do what with that method ?

Answer (score -1):

Use `getParent()` method to get name of parent or top level directory name.

```
import java.io.File;
public class DirectoryExample6 {
    public static void main(String args[]){
        File f = new File("D://tutorialData/java");
        String parent = f.getParent();
        System.out.println("Name of parent dir : "+parent);
    }
}
```

Source:  http://www.tutorialdata.com/examples/java/file-input-output/directory/get-name-of-parent-directory

Comment: Replace D://tutorialData/java with the relative path of a file in your eclipse project folder. Does it work ?