# this.getClass().getResource("").getPath() returns an incorrect path

Tags: java, classloader, filepath

I am currently making a small simple Java program for my Computer Science Final, which needs to get the path of the current running class. The class files are in the C:\2013\game\ folder.

To get this path, I call this code segment in my main class constructor:

```
public game(){
    String testPath = this.getClass().getResource("").getPath();
    //Rest of game
}
```

However, this command instead returns this String:  "/" despite the correct output being "C:/2013/game"
Additionally, I attempted to rectify this by using this code:

```
public game(){
    String testPath = this.getClass().getClassLoader().getResource("").getPath();
}
```

This returns a NullPointerException, which originates from the fact that getClassLoader() returns null, despite working on my Eclipse IDE. Any Ideas?

Comment: Why don't you pass the classname to the `getResource()` ?

Comment: "path of the current running class" is not well-defined in Java (it could be an URL, but it could also be entirely from memory, so no path is possible). This sounds like [a XY problem](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem). What problem are you *actually* trying to solve?

Comment: Indeed, you definitely need to look for a different solution for the undelying problem for which you incorrectly thought that the solution as stated in the question would be the right solution. The particular solution makes namely no utter sense and even if it works in a specific circumstance, it makes your application totally unportable (i.e. it runs in system X, but not in Y, Z, etc). I *guess* that `java.util.prefs.Preferences` is what you ultimately need. All answers posted so far which are continuing this silly solution are simply naive. I recommend to just ignore them.

Comment: @Joachim Sauer I'm trying to access a data folder that will be in the same folder as the  class files. Thus, I'll need to get the path of the current running class.

Comment: @user2465495: if you want to read data from your classpath, you should be using it *directly* via `getResource()`, not go the long way around using the `File` APIs (because in deployment, your classes and resources usually **aren't** Files (but entries in a ZIP file, for example)).

Comment: what do you want to do with the path?

Comment: @hjoachim-sauer if code is in a jar and data is in the same folder as the jar - easy to edit, will getResouce("../../myfile.csv") work? when the package + class is is a.b.MyClazz ?

Answer (score 8):

If you want to load a file in the same path as the code then I suggest you put it in the same root folder as the code and not the same path as the class.

Reason : class can be inside a jar, data file can be put in same jar but its more difficult to edit and update then.

Also suggest you see the preferences class suggested in comments : http://www.javacodegeeks.com/2011/09/use-javautilprefspreferences-instead-of.html though in some cases I think its okay to have your own data/ excel/csv/ java.util.Properties file

Not sure about why it is working in eclipse but I would suggest you focus on running it from a command prompt/ terminal as that is the 'real mode' when it goes live

You could just ask for your class

```
    String s = getClass().getName();
    int i = s.lastIndexOf(".");
    if(i > -1) s = s.substring(i + 1);
    s = s + ".class";
    System.out.println("name " +s);
    Object testPath = this.getClass().getResource(s);
    System.out.println(testPath);
```

This will give you

> name TstPath.class
>   file:/java/Projects/tests3b/build/classes/s/TstPath.class

Which is my eclipse build path ...

need to parse this to get the path where the class was loaded.

Remember:

1. App could be started from elsewhere
2. class can be in jar then path will be different (will point to a jar and file inside that
3. classpaths can be many at runtime and point 1
4. a class might be made at runtime via network/ Proxy / injection etc and thus not have a file source, so this is not a generic solution.
5. think what you want to acheive at a higher level and post that question. meaning why do you want this path?
6. do you want the app path :-

   File f = new File("./");
    f.getCanonicalPath();//...

So an app can be started from folder c:\app1\run\

The jar could be at c:\app1\libsMain\myapp.jar

and a helper jar could be at c:\commonlibs\set1

So this will only tell you where the JVM found your class, that may or maynot be what you need.

if inside a jar will give you some thing like this in unix or windows

> jar:file:c:\app\my.jar!/s/TstPath.class

If package is s and class is TstPath, you can be sure this will work as the class has to be there ...

now to parse this you can look for your class name and remove / or \ till you get path you want. String lastIndexOf will help

Answer (score 3):

You can use :

```
URL classURL = getClass().getProtectionDomain().getCodeSource().getLocation();
```

Answer (score 1):

```
ClassLoader loader = Test.class.getClassLoader();
System.out.println(loader.getResource("Test.class"));
```

also

```
Test.class.getProtectionDomain().getCodeSource().getLocation().getPath());
```

Answer (score 1):

The call to `getResource([String])` requires a path relative to the folder that contains the class it is being called from.  So, if you have the following, anything you pass into `MyClass.class.getResource([path]);` must be a valid path relative to the `com/putable/` package folder and it must point to a real file:

```
package com.putable;

public class MyClass{}
```

Using the empty string simply isn't valid, because there can never be a file name that equals the empty string.  But, you could do `getResource(getClass().getSimpleName())`.  Just remove the file name from the end of the path returned by that call and you will have the class directory you want.

Answer (score 0):

Try this.

```
import java.io.File;

public class TT {

    /**
     * @param args
     */
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub

        String path = TT.class.getResource("").getPath();
        File file = new File(path);
        System.out.println(file.getAbsolutePath());

    }

}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try use this code

```
public game()
{  
    String className = this.getClass().getSimpleName();  
    String testPath = this.getClass().getResource(className+".class");  
    System.out.println("Current Running Location is :"+testPath);   
}
```

visit the link  for more information
[Find where java class is loaded from](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/227486/find-where-java-class-is-loaded-from)

Answer (score 0):

Print out absolute path for a file in your classpath i.e. build/resources/main/someFileInClassPath.txt  Disclaimer, this is similar to another solution on this page that used TT.class..., but this did not work for me instead TT..getClassLoader()... did work for me.

```
import java.io.File;

public class TT {

    /**
     * @param args
     */
    public static void main(String[] args) {    
        String path = TT.getClassLoader().getResource("someFileInClassPath.txt").getPath();
        File file = new File(path);
        System.out.println(file.getAbsolutePath());

    }

}
```

Comment: Please do not copy-paste answers, the fact that this exact answer did not get accepted is because it has no explanation of why it does work.  Repeating it **without adding an explanation** is almost on the level of spam. Please edit your answer

Comment: I do not think this is a copy.  There is a fundamental difference, the old solution was " TT.class.getResource("").getPath();" which did not work for me.  I had to change TT.class to TT.getClassLoader().

Answer (score 0):

Because you used class.getResource(filePath).getpath() in a ***.jar** file. So the path includes **"!"**. If you want to get content of file in *.jar file, use the following code:

```
MyClass.class.getResourceAsStream("/path/fileName")
```