# Get Path of current file

Tags: java

How do I get the directory where the a .java file is located? I don't want to use `System.getProperty("user.dir")`, because that gives me the directory of the executable, and not the directory of the .java file that contains this line of code.

I need this because I'm developing a JSP web-app, and the Java code creates a .csv file on the server side and I want to make it available on the client side, but I would need to place the csv file where the location of the .html files are so that they could be downloaded.

My current folder structure is like:

Java Resources
->src
     ->.java file

WebContent
->.html file

Comment: `System.getProperty("user.dir")` gives you the directory you launched the executable from. A `.java` file does not exist at runtime.

Comment: A .class file would exist, would I be able to use that somehow?

Comment: You're creating the file, so you have control of where it's created.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Try this for asking for your class

```
String s = getClass().getName();
int i = s.lastIndexOf(".");
if(i > -1) s = s.substring(i + 1);
s = s + ".class";
System.out.println("name " +s);
Object testPath = this.getClass().getResource(s);
System.out.println(testPath);
```

this code snippet is from [this.getClass().getResource("").getPath() returns an incorrect path](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17027540/this-getclass-getresource-getpath-returns-an-incorrect-path)

Answer (score 6):

The source file might as well not exist. Java is a compiled language, it runs compiled files, .java files aren't necessary and thus might not be there at runtime.

You can however, get the location of the .class file, as it was previously suggested.