# Running an .exe based off of a class' location

Tags: java, windows, class, runtime, exe

I understand this line of code runs .exe's based of a specific set location

```
Runtime.getRuntime().exec("C:/Users/Username/Desktop/JavaApp.exe").waitFor();
```

but I need it to run the application based off of the location of the class it is ran in

Comment: I believe [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/227486/find-where-java-class-is-loaded-from) is what you're looking for.

Comment: It does show me where my class is even if it is moved but i need to be able to put it in the .exec; it doesn't work because it is an url not a string.

Comment: So I converted it to a String but how do I remove the file: part? It tries to run it like file:/C:/etc

Comment: [This answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/227640/207421) is specifically what you're looking for.

Answer (score 0):

I'm gonna go ahead and make an answer for this question.

I believe [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/227486/find-where-java-class-is-loaded-from) is what you're looking for.

---

For your comment asking about removal of the 'file' part from your string

Assuming you have a string called path which contains: "file:/C:/Users/Jon/Test/foo/Test.class"

You can call path.substring(5), which will return a string containing the text "/C:/Users/Jon/Test/foo/Test.class". The int just represents the index you want to start at for your new string, so you can change that as you need.