# Is there a way to programmatically tell a Java class's source?

Tags: java, classloader

The Java classloader loads the first class it can find with a matching name.  Is there any way to programmatically tell which one is loaded?

i.e., can I change the main below in a way that tells which ClassLoaderTest is loaded (other than invoking `test()`)?

```
echo "public class ClassLoaderTest { public static String test() { return \"1\"; } }" > ClassLoaderTest.java
javac ClassLoaderTest.java
mkdir one
mv ClassLoaderTest.class one
echo "public class ClassLoaderTest { public static String test() { return \"2\"; } }" > ClassLoaderTest.java
javac ClassLoaderTest.java
mkdir two
mv ClassLoaderTest.class two
echo "public class Main { public static void main(String[] _) {  System.out.println(ClassLoaderTest.test()); } }" > Main.java
javac Main.java
java -classpath one:two:. Main
java -classpath two:one:. Main
```

This outputs `1` then `2` based on the classpath order.

Comment: This question may help . . . 

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/227486/find-where-java-class-is-loaded-from

Comment: Unclear:  Do you want to find the class's source code, or simply find which directory the class was loaded from?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`getClass().getProtectionDomain().getCodeSource().getLocation()` - may have a null for JRE classes.

Comment: Thanks, that returned file:<root>/one/ and file:<root>/two/, respectively, which is what I was looking for.

Answer (score 1):

You want to analyze a Java class's source code. There are [byte code parsers like ASM](http://asm.ow2.org/) that are tailored for this purpose. When you look at the code for ASM, it locates a class's source by

```
getClassLoader()
  .getResourceAsStream(ClassLoaderTest.class.getName().replace('.', '/') + ".class")
```

which is sufficient if you only need the content of a class file and not its location (which might not even exist).

An alternative is the mentioned method via the `ProtectionDomain` which requires however additional security rights or `ClassLoader::getResource` which both might not work for a custom `ClassLoader` which do not store class files on a storage.