# How to find out which class is loaded at compile time?

Tags: java, compilation, compiler-errors

I got a project with lots of dependencies and somewhere in my code I'm implementing a class, like this:

```
public class MyApp extends org.some.BaseClass
```

Problem is, there are multiple jars in the dependencies providing the base class `org.some.BaseClass`, some of them containing specific abstract methods that I need to implement, others don't. Obviously, the compiler wants to use one of those base classes that I don't want to implement, and it fails with this:

```
[ERROR] MyApp is not abstract and does not override abstract method getSome() in org.some.BaseClass
```

Now, from here: [Find where java class is loaded from](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/227486/find-where-java-class-is-loaded-from) I learned about the jvm opt `-verbose:class` which lists all the classes that are being loaded and where it loads them from. This seems to be really nice for analyzation purposes. However, I guess since the compiler is still at work at that time and the classes have not yet been loaded fully, the source of `org.some.BaseClass` is not printed in the output. The compiler just fails and doesn't mention any details.

So, how can I find out what class is being compiled against at compile time? Is there another jvm flag that prints the same infos as `verbose:class` for files with compilation errors?

#### Update:

Solved by adding `-verbose` to the javac args. Turned out the wrong class came from a shaded jar that directly included all the classes from its dependencies. The IDE was unable to tell me about this, because that jar was also part of the project as a module.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From the `javac` manual:

> `-verbose` - Verbose output. This includes information about each class loaded and each source file compiled.

Comment: Thanks, that hint was helpful: I'm building the project with maven, and I needed to pass the verbose parameter to javac, not the java process executing maven.

Comment: To pass the verbose parameter to the Maven compiler run `mvn compile -DcompilerArgs=-verbose`.