# getClass() returning null but Foo.class working

Tags: java

When using the following I get a `NullPointerException`:

```
Class clazz = Foo.class;
String path = new File(clazz.getClass().getProtectionDomain().getCodeSource().getLocation().toURI().getPath()) + "";
```

However, it works when I use:

```
String path = new File(Foo.class.getProtectionDomain().getCodeSource().getLocation().toURI().getPath()) + "";
```

Is there any way around the `NullPointerException`?

Comment: Why do you call `getClass` on a `Class` instance? Do you really want to have the java class of java's `Class`?

Comment: `Foo.class` already is a `Class`. Don't call `getClass()` on it!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't have to invoke getClass on your clazz or you will get the Class.class instead of Foo.class.

So it should be:

```
Class clazz = Foo.class;
String path = new File(clazz.getProtectionDomain().getCodeSource().getLocation().toURI().getPath()) + "";
```

Answer (score 3):

You should call `getClass()` on an *instance* of a class.

```
MyClass myClassInstance = new MyClass();
Class clazz = myClassInstance.getClass();
```

You are trying to call it on the *class Object*

Comment: This still returns `NullPointerException`

Comment: @tank - You will have to check which method in that chain is returning `null`.

Answer (score 0):

It depends on how the class was loaded - like for instance if the class was loaded from the [Bootstrap classloader](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Java_Classloader).

See [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/19494116/823393) for a more complete answer.