# How to get full path to method, where it was called in java?

Tags: java, logging, log4j

how can I get full path to class, where my method was called. I have a method, which write logs. I want to know, where it was called.

Comment: Possible duplicate of: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/227486/find-where-java-class-is-loaded-from

Comment: Ok, I had to call Thread.currentThread().getStackTrace().

Comment: @SergeiPodlipaev If you believe you have solved your issue on your own it would be good if you answer your question yourself. If you have used information from other sources ideally you would mark the answer as `Community Wiki`. This way it will appear as solved.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I used  `log.debug("" + Arrays.toString(Thread.currentThread().getStackTrace()));` to get full classpath where my method was called from.

Answer (score 0):

```
System.getProperty("user.dir")
```

will get you the directory.
If you want the class name as well use

```
this.getClass().getName();
```

Comment: My method is static, so I cant use it.