# Gradle - Launch4j - Current Working Directory

Tags: java, gradle, command, exe, launch4j

I am creating an exe file using Launch4j plug-in in Gradle. My intention is to get the directory where I am while executing the exe file that is placed in another directory. For example, the exe file is placed in "C:\Utilities" and my current directory is "C:\temp". When I execute "C:\Utilities\my.exe", I would like to get "C:\temp" in my main method.

I tried this to send the result of %CD% as a system property -

```
createExe {
    mainClassName = 'com.eldho.mp3tools.Mp3ToolsMain'
    jvmOptions = ['-Dworking.dir="%CD%"']
}
```

But, it is turning up blank inside my method.

I also tried this inside the method -

```
Path currentRelativePath = Paths.get("");
String s = currentRelativePath.toAbsolutePath().toString();
logger.info("Current relative path is: " + s);
```

This gives the directory where the exe file is (C:\Utilities).

Any help is appreciated.

Comment: Are you trying to get the path where the exe is being run from? If so why not try a more Java-centric approach? This - https://stackoverflow.com/a/227640 - allows you to get the location of a Class. What does it output when running from your exe? Worth a try.

Comment: I am looking for the directory where I am while running the exe that is in a different directory.

Answer (score 0):

A possible solution is to 'null' out the chdir property of the Launch4j configuration, by default it uses '.' but that is only interpreted once the wrapper starts your Jar file.

```
launch4j {
   mainClassName = 'com.eldho.mp3tools.Mp3ToolsMain'
   chdir = ''
}
```

Discussed in this [issue](https://github.com/TheBoegl/gradle-launch4j/issues/79)